# Definition of forecasting period in time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, definition

I am new to forecasting time series. The team that I am working with keep referring to forecasting period as lag. For example we have 20 month of data and we would like to create 5 month forecast. Is it appropriate (industry accepted) to call 5 month forecast as 5 month lag?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, lag(n) would refer to moving an actual value ahead by n periods. It would be better to call this a 5 month *forecast horizon*.